# Realizing real-valued (singular) top-degree cocycles as measures on an oriented manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to work out the relationships between these 3 types of objects on a smooth oriented $n$-manifold $X$:

1. A top-degree differential form $\alpha \in \Omega^n(X,\mathbb{R})$.
2. A top-degree (ordinary singular) $\mathbb{R}$-valued cocycle $\beta \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(C_n(X),\mathbb{R})$, with $\omega \circ \partial_{n+1} = 0$ the cocycle condition.

   (Note: by e.g. Lee's Smooth Manifolds, Ch. 18, we can use the chain complex of *smooth* chains to work with singular homology and cohomology on $X$.)
3. A "nice" real-valued (signed) measure $\mu$ on (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of) $X$.

I understand two of the relationships so far:

- The map $1\rightarrow 2$ takes an $n$-form $\alpha$
  to the $\mathbb{R}$-valued cocycle $\beta$ given
  on smooth $n$-simplices $\sigma$ by $\beta(\sigma) = \int_\sigma \alpha$;
  this $\beta$ is a cocycle because $\alpha$ is closed (and by applying Stokes' theorem for pseudomanifolds, and the fact that a $\mathbb{Z}$-singular-homology boundary is necessarily the boundary of some oriented pseudomanifold mapped into $X$).
- The map $1 \rightarrow 3$ uses e.g. theorems from real analysis like the [Riesz-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X)) or Caratheodory extension, to send a form $\alpha$
  to the (signed) measure uniquely extended from the one given by $\mu(U) = \int_U \alpha$ for open sets $U$.

---

I was wondering, is there a way to construct a natural map $2\rightarrow 3$ which "commutes" with the maps above?

My suspicion is that this $2\rightarrow 3$ would give more general measures than those obtained from the mapping $1 \rightarrow 3$, e.g. Dirac-delta measures.

However, afterwards would it make sense to say two measures in the image of $2\rightarrow 3$ are "cohomologous" if their difference is the image of a coboundary?